# Run two instances of the same C++ program simultaneously

Tags: makefile

I've got a C++ program with a Makefile, building (g++) and running on Windows cmd. Thing is, sometimes it takes a while to run and save the results, and I want to run it with different parameters at the same time so that I can do something else while I wait for the first instance to finish. It doesn't work though, because of the executable I guess:

```
>make
g++    -c -o main.o main.cpp
Assembler messages:
Fatal error: can't create main.o: Permission denied
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: The first error you get is not related to running simultaneously, because object files aren't the programs you run. Why you get this specific error is impossible to say, can you please to e.g. `ls -l main.o` to see its rights and flags and owner?

Comment: Make your program configurable so you don't need to recompile when you change parameters.

Comment: The second error you get because your rules are wrongly written, for example you have no rule to make e.g. `utils2.o`. And more specifically you have no rule to make `main2.o`.

Comment: Doesn't the rule main2 make main2.o, though? That's what I don't get. I used to have a main that built main.o.

Comment: I believe you're asking a so-called XY question. This means that your assumption what's going on and your interpretation may already be flawed, and so your question how to solve this is flawed as well. Consider taking a step back and telling us more of the background of your task.

Comment: Ulrich, I erased the part about the Makefile attempt and am focusing on the need to re-compile and run the same program while an instance of it is running.

Comment: You have a rule to make `main2`, which depends on the file `main2.o`. The rule then continues to create `main2.o`. ***And here's the original problem***: You seem to naming your executable file `main.o` and not just `main` (or `main.exe` on Windows) which would be the normal. The `.o` suffix is for *object files* which are then to be linked into the executable program.

Comment: Ahhh I get it, I didn't know that about object files. Thank you! I changed it to .exe and it worked as I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems: The one you ask about, and the reason you ask this question in the first place.

Lets start with the problem you have...

Judging by the `Makefile` you show, you have it all wrong.

Rules are in the format

```
target: sources_the_target_depend_on
```

The target is usually a file that need to be created. For an object file that is the name of the actual object file itself. The source files that the object files then depend on should be on the right-hand side.

To take an example from you `Makefile` (before you edited it away):

```
graph2: graph2.o
    g++ -g -c graph.cpp -o graph2.o
```

Here you tell `make` that the file `graph2` depends on the file `graph2.o`, and then it creates the `graph2.o` file. That's wrong. The rule should be that the file `graph2.o` depends om the file `graph.cpp` and go on to generate the file `graph2.o`:

```
graph2.o: graph.cpp
    g++ -g -c graph.cpp -o graph2.o
```

This indirectly leads to the problem you have, with this line (deduced from your error and the `Makefile`):

```
main: main.o utils.o graph.o heuristics.o
    g++ -g main.cpp -o main.o utils.o graph.o heuristics.o
```

This contains the same error as discussed above: You say that the file `main` depends on `main.o` and then the rule create `main.o`. Your rule should be

```
main: main.cpp utils.o graph.o heuristics.o
    g++ -g main.cpp -o main utils.o graph.o heuristics.o
```

Note also how I no longer name the executable file `main.o`, as that is supposed to be used for object files.

---

Now lets continue with the reason you have the problem in the first place: That you need to edit the code to change data or values.

This is a problem that you need to solve. One common way to solve it is through *command line arguments*. If your program parses the command line arguments passed to your program you can pass it the values that could change from run to run.

How to do this is whole chapter on its own, so I wont give you any more details. There are plenty of tutorials online.

---

Lastly, you can simplify your `Makefile` considerably, by using [*implicit rules*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#toc-Using-Implicit-Rules) and variables.

I would simply create the `Makefile` to look something like this

```
# The compiler to use
CXX = g++

# Flags to pass to the compiler (add warnings when building)
CXXFLAGS = -Wall

# The main executable file to generate
TARGET = main

# List the object files needed to generate the main executable file
OBJECTS = main.o utils.o graph.o heuristics.o

# The all target depends on your main executable file
# Also as the first target in the Makefile, if no specific target is specified
# this will be the one that is used (it's the "default" target for the Makefile)
all: $(TARGET)

# The main executable file depends on the object files
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
```

This is really it. the object files will be built automatically from their respective source files, and then the executable program will be linked using the object files listed.

Comment: Thank you! I wrote my original Makefile based on some answers I saw here since I don't understand the syntax that well yet and since it worked I thought it was fine until now.